# ES6 class features function called inside function

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

I tried some stuffs in ES6 javascript , and i've got a problem with
    trying to using function inside a function and it gots error..

```
       class Model {
            constructor(properties) {
              this.properties = properties;
            }

            functionA() {
              return functionB() * 3;
            }
            functionB(){
              return 5 * 3;
            }
        }
```

does this code going to work , i mean calling the functionB inside of functionA() ?

Comment: Try `this.functionB()`

Answer (score 1):

Would you ask the same question if you had written it in the following form:

```
function Model(properties) {
    this.properties = properties;
}

Model.prototype.functionA = function () {
    return /*insert function B call*/ * 3;
};

Model.prototype.functionB = function () {
    return 5 * 3;
};
```

ES6 is still governed by the same JS scoping rules and ES6 classes is just syntaxic sugar for what you see above.

Therefore, you must use `this.functionB` just like you did in the constructor to set the `properties` member on the newly constructed `Model` instance.

Comment: well thnx ! , its seem to be work.. can closed the post..